# Is there Django List View model sort?

Tags: python, django

I'm using `ListView` in my Class Based Views and I was wondering if there was a way to display the model object set on the template by sorting it. This is what I have so far:

My views:

```
class Reviews(ListView):
    model = ProductReview
    paginate_by = 50
    template_name = 'review_system/reviews.html'
```

The model `ProductReview` has a `date_created` field. I'd like to sort the date in descending order. How can I achieve this?

Comment: It may be possible that you may want the same ordering in multiple views. In that case, you may also look into [`Meta order`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#ordering) which is set on the model itself.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Set the [`ordering`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/class-based-views/mixins-multiple-object/#django.views.generic.list.MultipleObjectMixin.ordering) attribute for the view.

```
class Reviews(ListView):
    model = ProductReview
    paginate_by = 50
    template_name = 'review_system/reviews.html'

    ordering = ['-date_created']
```

If you need to change the ordering dynamically, you can use [`get_ordering`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-multiple-object/#multipleobjectmixin) instead.

```
class Reviews(ListView):
    ...
    def get_ordering(self):
        ordering = self.request.GET.get('ordering', '-date_created')
        # validate ordering here
        return ordering
```

If you are always sorting a fixed date field, you may be interested in the [`ArchiveIndexView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/class-based-views/generic-date-based/#archiveindexview).

```
from django.views.generic.dates import ArchiveIndexView

class Reviews(ArchiveIndexView):
    model = ProductReview
    paginate_by = 50
    template_name = 'review_system/reviews.html'
    date_field = "date_created"
```

Note that `ArchiveIndexView` won't show objects with a date in the future unless you set `allow_future` to `True`.

Comment: I like the ArchiveIndexView, it does the trick, but the template has a table that allows sorting columns by clicking on headers. When I do that, this doesn't work, do you know how I could make it work there as well?

Comment: If you're sorting by other fields, it sounds like the archive index view is not suitable.

Comment: @user3118363 please ask a new question, I’m not on Stack Overflow much any more so can’t help in the comments

Answer (score 10):

Why don't you override the [`get_queryset`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_queryset) method like this:

```
class Reviews(ListView):
    model = ProductReview
    paginate_by = 50
    template_name = 'review_system/reviews.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return YourModel.objects.order_by('model_field_here')
```

Comment: I'll try this, but your method is missing a def

Comment: This did not have any errors rendering or executing, but the order_by did not work.

Comment: @DeA Overriding `get_queryset` and using `order_by` should work, although with `ListView` you might prefer to override `ordering` or `get_ordering` instead.

Comment: This works perfectly well. I had to do a custom order using `Case`, `When`, `Then`, `Value` clause which I could not do with `get_ordering`.