# Django 2 - pagination does not propperly work

Tags: django, templates, pagination, view

first of all, thank for reading my question :)
I'm currently working on a small Blog platform and i want to implement pagination for all my Post elemets.
therefor i modified my view.py and the actual .html template.
The problem now is that each time i visit the post_list.html page and i click on next nothing happends.. What the matter here:

**post_list.html**

```
{% extends 'quickblog/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    {% for post in posts %}
        <br>
        <div class="post">
            <h1><u><a href="{% url 'post_detail' pk=post.pk %}">{{ post.title }}</a></u></h1>
            <p>{{ post.text|linebreaksbr }}</p>
            <div class="date">
                <a>published by: {{ post.author }}</a><br>
                <a>published at: {{ post.published_date }}</a><br>
                <a>tags: {{ post.tag }}</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
        <div class="pagination">
        <span class="step-left">
         {% if posts.has_previous %}
            <a href="?page=1">&laquo; first</a>
            <a href="?page={{ posts.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
            {% endif %}

        <span class="current">
            Page {{ posts.number }} of {{ posts.paginator.num_pages }}.
        </span>

        {% if posts.has_next %}
            <a href="?page={{ posts.next_page_number }}">Next</a>
            <a href="?page={{ posts.paginator.num_pages }}">Last &raquo;</a>
        {% endif %}
    </span>
   </div>
{% endblock %}
```

**views.py**

```
def post_list(request):
    list_posts = Post.objects.get_queryset().order_by('created_date')
    paginator = Paginator(list_posts, 15)  # Show 15 Posts per page

    page = request.GET.get('posts')
    posts = paginator.get_page(page)
    return render(request, 'quickblog/post_list.html', {'posts': posts})
```

Comment: Don't use `list` as a variable name. `list` is a builtin type in python, and by using that name for something else, you are likely to cause confusing bugs.

Comment: Thanks for this hint :) i will try right away

Comment: Still same issue. i renamed it to list_posts

Comment: Yes. The comment was just a tip about good practice. Your bug is caused by something else. I've submitted an answer with a suggested solution to this specific problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your template you use `page` as query parameter. So you should use that in the view as well.

template:

```
<a href="?page={{ posts.next_page_number }}">Next</a>
```

view:

```
page = request.GET.get('page')  # not .get('posts')
```

Comment: 5/5 Star Answere :D
Seems that i still have the eyes of an beginner.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As pagination works on ordered data you need to either append order_by after your query or use default ordering in your models as specified in the below link

[Link of another stackowerflow Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44033670/python-django-rest-framework-unorderedobjectlistwarning)

Hope this helps.