# how to implement sorting in django site

Tags: python, django, sorting

I have a shopping site and I want implement sorting products in my site
I know how order_by works but I don't know how to pass arguments through url to check it
I use class base view (ListView)

my view:

```
class ProductList(ListView):
    template_name = 'products/store.html'
    paginate_by = 8

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Product.objects.get_active_products()
```

I use dropdown (with tag a) for finding witch order user want to sort

for example in amazon when you sort items "&s=price-asc" has added to url that means we sort ascending

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42698234

Answer (score 1):

You can use dict with request parameters from `self.request.GET` in `get_queryset(self)` method.