# ordering is not working with django model seralizer

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am using 2.2.16 django versiong and 3.11.2 django_rest_framework version and using serializers.ModelSerializer CRUD operation is working but ordering is not working.

models.py code is below,

```
class Ticket(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=255)
    notes = models.TextField()
```

eg: code in seralizers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class Ticket(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    title = serializers.CharField()
    description = serializers.CharField(required=False)
    notes = serializers.CharField(required=False)

class Meta(object):
    fields = '__all__'
    depth = 1
    model = Ticket
    ordering_fields = ["title"]

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(Ticket, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

When i do GET operation as below, ordering is not working with query parameters

eg:

```
http://localhost:4200/api/ticket?ordering=title
```

Above api call is returning add data with default ordering as ID (auto created field), but not returning in the assenting of title field (which is a char field).

How can I fix this? Also how can i add filtering to the same

```
eg: http://localhost:4200/api/ticket?title=abc  # this should give me result of only matching title field with abc or starts with abc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set a default ordering for you model, you can do it in your model's `Meta` class:

```py
class Ticket(models.Model):
    ...
    class Meta:
        ordering = ["title"]
```

As docs says in [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/options/#ordering)

Or, you can do the sorting in your `ListView`, you can see it in [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42698197/is-there-django-list-view-model-sort).

But if you want to have filter and search in your api, you should declare `ordering_filters` and `search_fields` in you view. Read about it in [DRF Docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/)

Comment: i am using DRF and hence tried to use filter_backends = [filters.OrderingFilter] as well and ordering_fields, but its having any effect. 
I don't want any default ordering  from backend, based on query parameters  eg: ordering=title it should filter or ordering=-title it should filter in descending order etc..

Comment: Actually i was implementing it in serializers.ModelSerializer instead of viewSet , once i created it in viewSet it is working

Comment: Did it finally solve your problem ? @NaggappanRamukannan